# What's the fastest way to fetch content for my jQuery Mobile front page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jsonp

I'm using [tabletop](https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop) to store the text/content of my jQuery Mobile app in a Google Doc, so when someone visits my app, the first thing it should do is fetch the content (JSONP request).

Assuming jQuery Mobile loads/renders before the JSONP request is complete (which isn't necessarily the case), it should display a loading indicator until the request is complete, and then the request callback will render the data and it will need to trigger a re-rendering to enhance things like `<ul>` elements.

How can I do this so the timing lines up with jQuery Mobile loading/rendering?

I was thinking of doing the JSONP request in the `<head>` (not inside an event) and rendering the data to the content `<div>` when it's complete, but I'd need to trigger the re-render, and if I trigger that before jQuery Mobile is rendered, it will break, etc.

In case that didn't make sense, here's a more relateable example: say you want your front page to display the most recent tweets on a particular account. When you load the page, it fetches the tweets. How do you time it so when the fetch is complete, it can render properly?

Comment: Why not just put the "re-rendering" into the JSONP request's callback?

Comment: @G_M because what if the callback is triggered before the page is rendered? You can't call .trigger("create") before the page is created the first time or you'll get an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to the `pageinit` event to make your AJAX request. This assures that the jQuery Mobile pseudo-page will be initialized by the time the AJAX request returns. That's nice because then you know the state of your dynamically added code, it's not initialized.

For example:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#myLandingPage', function () {
    $.ajax({
        ...,
        success : function (response) {
            //do your work on the response

            //then when you add the HTML output to the DOM just initialize it
            $("#some-container").html(htmlOutput).trigger("create");
        }
    });
});
```

I would like to suggest that you do the initial JSONP request with a server-side language since your server most likely has really good bandwidth and your user may not (especially if they're on a mobile device).

Comment: This will work, but I will lose the time between the document loading and when the `pageinit` event is called. It's not a huge deal, but it'd be nice if I could start my HTTP request as soon as possible.

Comment: @TobiasFünke You could update the callback function of your AJAX request to first check for the status of the page, whether or not it's been initialized, then either initialize or update it. jQuery Mobile adds classes to lots of elements when they are initialized, so you could check if a page has been initialized by checking for one of these classes, like: `if ($("#my-page-div").hasClass("ui-page")) {/*already initialized*/} else {/*not initialized yet*/}`. Although I'm not sure how soon you can show the loading spinner.

Comment: Thanks Jasper, that's exactly what I did and it's working. I'm doing it outside of an event, so it loads immediately, and I add `ui-loading` class to `<body>` and remove it when it's done